# Nextjs: render page or show 404 page based on user data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We are currently working on a Nextjs project which includes a number of dynamic pages. We have come to a stage where we are defining the dynamic paths using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. So far we managed to define 404 pages in dynamic pages with a similar structure to the below:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const { id } = context.params
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
    const user = await response.json()
    
    return {
        props: { user },
        notFound: Object.keys(user).length === 0
    }
}

export function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: 'blocking'
    }
}
```

Using version 10's `notFound` value and `fallback: blocking` allows us to have the page return a 404 status code (for some reason `fallback: true` returns a 200 status code).

The issue we currently have is to display a 404 page to pages that depend on user data such as username or user locale. One way we thought we could solve this is by having those pages as Server Side generated rather than Static Site generated by using `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const userId = getCookie('user_id')

    const response = await fetch(`___/checkUserAccess/${userId}`)
    const access = await response.json()
    
    return {
        props: { ... },
        notFound: !access.userAllowed
    }
}
```

I suppose I am answering my own question here as going for Server Side for these pages to show 404 pages based on user data seems logical. However the concern is the impact it may have on the website as a whole. These pages could easily end up being hundreds of pages.

Should we be concerned about this? Or maybe there's another way to go about solving this?

Comment: You essentially have 2 options: use SSR like you mention in your question, or make the user check on the client.

Comment: @juliomalves Ah yes, my bad thanks - updated the question.

Yep thought so, since we need the pages to return a 404 error - SSR might be the only option.